# Deploy Eclipse Plug In for different Eclipse versions

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am building an Eclipse plug-in under Oxygen, and deploying it via an update site. This works very well, as long as the Eclipse version where I want to install the plug-in is also Oxygen. If I want to use an older version, like Neon or Mars it will not be able to install the plug in as it cannot resolve necessary dependencies e.g. 'org.eclipse.jdt.core'. Do I need to manually configure my plug-in somewhere so it will run also under older versions of Eclipse?

If I manually set the required version for the dependencies in the Manifest or the plug-in feature, it will work, but I am sure that this is not the way it is intended to work.

Comment: Use version ranges for your dependencies. In Eclipse/OSGi _Semantic Versioning_ is used, which gives you the guarantee if it works with e. g. 1.2.3, it will also work with 1.42.0 (but maybe not with 2.1.3). Make sure, it works also with the lower bound of the version range (in your case, with the plug-ins of Mars).

Comment: Nice idea, haven't thought of that... But where can I get the corresponding version numbers?

Comment: I recommend using the lowest Eclipse version you want to support  (e. g. Mars) as your target platform. The version of those plug-ins can be used as (inclusive) minimum version and the (exclusive) maximum version is if the minimum version is `x.y.z`, `(x+1).0.0`, e. g. min `3.10.0` (inclusive) => max `4.0.0` (exclusive). At least the tests should be done with all supported platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use **version ranges** instead of a specific version for your dependencies.

In Eclipse/OSGi [***Semantic Versioning***](https://www.osgi.org/wp-content/uploads/SemanticVersioning.pdf) is used. This means if it works with a dependency of version `1.2.3`, it should also work with version `1.2.34` or `1.42.0`, but maybe not with version `2.0.0` or higher.

I recommend using the lowest Eclipse version you want to support (e. g. Mars) as your target platform and use the versions of the *Required Plug-ins* / *Imported Packages* from the target platform as the *Minimum Version (Inclusive)*. As *Minimum Version* use the next major version *(Exclusive)*, e. g. if the (inclusive) minimum version is `1.2.3`, the (exclusive) maximum version will be `2.0.0`. It is recommended to run the test on all supported platforms.